# How to concatenate the distinct values of each row and partition by specific dimensions in Athena SQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, concatenation, amazon-athena

I concatenate string values ‘product’ from different rows in Athena using the ARRAY_AGG function in SQL like below:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
    date_range,
    ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_AGG(product)), ', ') AS concatenated_products
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customer_id, date_range
```

However, I want it to partition by ‘customer_id’ and ‘date_range’ and this query gave me the result without parition by customer and date_range.

I’ve tried my best but I still can’t figure it out, please help me with this.

The attached is raw data. Thank you so much!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1cCQ.png)

Comment: _"The attached is raw data"_ - no, you did not, you have attached an image of the raw data (and it is a bit useless). Please share sample input (ideally in text form) and both actual and desired outputs.

Comment: As for the question - your query looks fine, check the data (also you claim that it has not provided expected result but have not added any proof for that).

Comment: Also your expectation is wrong at least in one row - 2222 for 2023/04/03 has both gas and air as far as I can see.